# PostgreSQL calculate prefix combinations after split

Tags: postgresql

I do have a string as entry, of the form `foo:bar:something:221`. I'm looking for a way to generate a table with all prefixes for this string, like:

- `foo`
- `foo:bar`
- `foo:bar:something`
- `foo:bar:something:221`

I wrote the following query to split the string, but can't figure out where to go from there:

`select unnest(string_to_array('foo:bar:something:221', ':'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string_agg` as a window function.  The default frame is from the beginning of the partition to the current row:

```
SELECT string_agg(s, ':') OVER (ORDER BY n) 
FROM unnest(string_to_array('foo:bar:something:221', ':')) WITH ORDINALITY AS u(s, n);
      string_agg
-----------------------
 foo
 foo:bar
 foo:bar:something
 foo:bar:something:221
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is to simulate a loop over all elements, then take the sub-array from the input for each element index:

```
with data(input) as (
  values (string_to_array('foo:bar:something:221', ':'))
)
select array_to_string(input[1:g.idx], ':')
from data
  cross join generate_series(1, cardinality(input)) as g(idx);
```

`generate_series(1, cardinality(input))` generates as many rows as the array has elements. And the expression `input[1:g.idx]` takes the "sub-array" starting with the first up to the "idx" one. As the output is an array, I use `array_to_string` to re-create the representation with the `:`